# How to show splash video during launching appication in sencha touch2

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have done application using sencha, **using phone gap build i am packaging these files.** Right now i am able to show splash .png image during launching appication. But i need to show splash video to user while launching application. So i have added in place of source image path added video path not getting splash video. I want to know about **is sencha touch2 support splash video or not?.** if it support means which type video format it will support. can any tell me how to achieve this one in sencha touch2.

**Here is code for splash image: Config.xml(Working)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.phonegap.example"
        versionCode="10" 
        version   = "1.0.0">
    <!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->
    <name>ABC</name>
<gap:splash src="resources/splash/def.png" width="1024" height="768" />
<gap:splash src="resources/splash/def.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<icon src="resources/icons/xyz.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />
<icon src="resources/icons/xyz.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" width="100"  height="100"/> 
</widget>
```

**Here is code for Splash video: config.xml (Not working)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.phonegap.example"
        versionCode="10" 
        version   = "1.0.0">
    <!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->
    <name>ABC</name>
<gap:splash src="resources/splash/AVIFile.avi.mp4" width="1024" height="768" />
<gap:splash src="resources/splash/AVIFile.avi.mp4" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<icon src="resources/icons/xyz.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />
<icon src="resources/icons/xyz.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" width="100"  height="100"/> 
</widget>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the splash image as you have given in Phonegap or Sencha. Now, add the video in index.html file say by using IFRAME or html5 video tag; provide an ID to the tag you are using.

Now, access the element by ID in Sencha `launch` function and remove it from DOM. You should get what you want.

Comment: Hi i have done as per you told. in index file i have added html5 video tag and given sourch path of video file. in launch function i am accessing the id of video tag and called function play(); but it showing poster of video not playing. below i have given code can you tell me what i have done mistake in my code **Index code** **'<body>
<div id="appLoadingIndicator">
<video id="video1" width="420">
    <source src="resources/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="resources/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div>
</body>'**

Comment: **Launch code** **'launch: function () {      
        var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");
        this.myVideo.play();'**

Comment: i am getting error in safari console like this **'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'myVideo.play()')**

Comment: First of all, do not put the play function in sencha "launch" function. In launch function you should remove the splash. Write a script tag just below the video TAG, access the video and execute play function. For any issue, do update your question and show the source code there.